# undefined method 'file_name' for nil:NilClas

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails index page that renders a partial. It was once working but now I am getting an `undefined method 'file_name' for nil:NilClass`.

The FEA_Ref index page calls a partial to render it's list of references. This partial is shared across three different reference pages. It works for the other two, but not FEA_REF. I even looked inside the rails console to make sure the table still associated with reference_file_id, so I'm not sure what would cause to all of sudden think the reference file was nil

**app/views/fea_refs/index.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'referenences', object: @fea_refs %>
```

**app/views/application/_references.html.erb**

```
<ul>
<%= object.each do |reference| %>
<li><%= reference.reference_file.file_name %></li>
<li><%= reference.reference_file.title %></li>
<li><%= reference.page_number %></li>
<li><%= reference.section %></li>
<ul>
```

**My FEA_Ref Model**

```
class FeaRef < ActiveRecord :: Base
 validates :reference_file presence: true
 belongs_to :reference_file
end
```

Comment: here it should be  `validates :reference_file, presence: true`.  I think because of this its not storing `reference_file` for you and you are getting it as nil.

Comment: Check in _references.html.erb, that if there are any values present in object, if they are check if for any row filename is not blank.
You can also use `pry` gem as debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add a comma in validation

  ```
  validates :reference_file, presence: true
  ```
- To avoid errors in future use `try` where you are chaining more than 2 times:

  ```
  <li><%= reference.reference_file.try(:file_name) %></li>
  <li><%= reference.reference_file.try(:title) %></li>
  ```